# How to start/stop tomcat service from java program with the help of a bat file?

Tags: java, tomcat, cmd

Currently i am logged in to my system as administrator and trying to start/stop the tomcat service from java code.when i execute my program i am getting a prompt saying "Enter the password for Administrator:" in the console.

my java program:

```
package Snomed.Snomed;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Utility {

public static void main (String args[] ) 
    {
 try{ 
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c  startup.bat\"");
BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             String l;
             while((l=BR.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.print(l);
             }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

}

}
```

I have read some where that this problem can be overcome by writing a batch script (bat file) for running with admin privileges.So how do i go about making my own batch file.can someone provide me the script or batch file??

Comment: Can you provide us the PATH where tomcat is installed? Also, remove [tag:cmd] and add [tag:batch-file].

Comment: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.92

Comment: Has `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.92` folder got `catalina.bat` or `Tomcat7.exe` files?